# How to convert text to docx by converting text to pdf and pdf to docx in android

Tags: android

I want to convert text to docx format in android app .I want to know how I could achieve the same.

I tried directly converting from text to docx first.
I tried implementing Apache POI and Aspose library but I didn't find my solution. Aspose library on runtime gave error of "Duplicate API ", I checked Aspose forum it is not resolved yet .I tried whatever it is told.

I tried implementing text to pdf it is done.
Now I want to know how to convert from pdf to docx?

Can anybody help with proper functioning details to achieve this task ? or any other suggestion so that text to docx can be converted?

```
// Below code is for converting directly from text to docx  .
// This is using Apache POI but it is not importing classes after adding library


private void docxFormat()
    {

        XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument();

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("yourfilepath/filename.docx"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(String s:lines) {


            XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph = xwpfDocument.createParagraph();


            XWPFRun xwpfRun = xwpfParagraph.createRun();

            xwpfRun.setText(s);

        }
        xwpfDocument.write(fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }

// Anybody any suggestion for converting text to docx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert a Text file to Word formats such as DOC, DOCX, RTF and to many other formats (PDF, XPS, HTML etc) by using the following [Aspose.Words for Android via Java](https://products.aspose.com/words/android-java) API's code:

```
try
{
    String licString = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Aspose.Words.Android.lic";
    String inputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/input.txt";
    String outputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/output.docx";

    com.aspose.words.License lic = new com.aspose.words.License();
    lic.setLicense(licString, this);

    com.aspose.words.Document doc = new com.aspose.words.Document(inputPath);
    doc.save(outputPath);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks...I want to know It is paid  or free which you are referring ?

Comment: You need to buy license for commercial uses. However, we can issue you a 30-day temporary license for evaluation. If you want to test Aspose.Words without the evaluation version limitations, you can request a 30-day Temporary License. Please refer to [How to get a Temporary License](https://purchase.aspose.com/temporary-license)?